# What is the best way to create a python dictionary from a string?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a large file in which I will parse about 1.9E8 lines.

During each iteration I will create a temporary dictionary to send to another method, which will give me the output I want.

Since the file is too large, I can't open it with readlines() method.

So my last resort to make it faster is during the parsing.

I already have two options for generating the dictionary. **optionB** has better performance than **optionA** and I am aware I could try regex, however I am not familiar with it.  I am willing to receive insights of better alternatives, if there is any.

**Expected input:** `"A@1:100;2:240;...:.."` *input may be longer, it can have more groups and their frequencies*

```
def optionA(line):
    _id, info = line.split("@")
    data = {}
    for g_info in info.split(";"):
        k, v = g_info.split(":")
        data[k] = v
    return data

def optionB(line):
    _id, info = line.split("@")
    return dict(map(lambda i: i.split(":"), info.split(";")))
```

**Expected output:** `{'1': '100', '2': '240'}`

I am open for receiving any recomendation!

Comment: How good are you with regexes?

Comment: If the file is so large that reading it is already a problem, then what makes you think that having all the data an in *in-memory dictionary* will be any better?

Comment: @poke, please, read it carefully once again. _I will create a **temporary** dictionary to send to another method_. This dictionary will be the input of a method.

Comment: If you only want to find stuff that begins with @ or a ;, followed by some numbers, a :, more numbers, and ends with a ;, then it shouldn't be too hard to create with regexes.

Comment: Yes, I did read the question. But it still doesn’t answer how having all the data in your memory as a dictionary will not cause you performance problems, when you already have problems just reading it from a file.

Comment: @poke, I will not store a large dictionary in my memory. That is a problem I already solved. This dictionary will be the input for another method which will work on a pdf (probability density function)

Comment: @JAW, could you elaborate an answer with a regex, please? But I would like to know in terms of performance as well.

Comment: You have a dictionary; where do you think the dictionary is stored when you pass it around to other methods? In your memory.

Comment: Why not just `timeit` for both versions?

Comment: Dude, you don't know my code, why don't you just focus on the actual question? I already solved the dictionary problem. I parse the file, read the line, create a dictionary, pass it to another method X. This method X will read this dictionary and compute the pdf and store the result in a global dictionary, after that the temporary dictionary is deleted. So now, if you could please focus on my original qestion, I would be pleased.

Comment: @sobolevn, I wanted to know of more options too. But good call, lemme time it.

Comment: @poke, OP is processing line-by-line.  It sounds like the temp dictionary only exists for one line at a time.  The OP is not storing all the dictionaries for all the lines in memory.

Comment: Exactly @MarkTolonen =)

Comment: @sobolevn, optionB is better as I just saw, but still, how would be the regex alternative for this? I am not familiar with it that much, even though I am reading now a bit about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick example of a regex to parse the line:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'A@1:100;2:240'
>>> data = re.search(r'@(\d+):(\d+);(\d+):(\d+)',line).groups()
>>> D = {data[0]:data[1],data[2]:data[3]}
>>> D
{'1': '100', '2': '240'}
```

Here's some timings with:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'@(\d+):(\d+);(\d+):(\d+)')

def optionA(line):
    _id, info = line.split("@")
    data = {}
    for g_info in info.split(";"):
        k, v = g_info.split(":")
        data[k] = v
    return data

def optionB(line):
    _id, info = line.split("@")
    return dict(map(lambda i: i.split(":"), info.split(";")))

def optionC(line):
    data = regex.search(line).groups()
    return {data[0]:data[1],data[2]:data[3]}

line = 'A@1:100;2:240'
```

Times:

```
C:\>py -m timeit -s "import x" "x.optionA(x.line)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.01 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "import x" "x.optionB(x.line)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.15 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "import x" "x.optionC(x.line)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.88 usec per loop
```

**Edit:** With the slight change in requirements, I tried a `findall` for `optionC` and a slightly different version of `optionA`:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(\d+):(\d+)')

def optionA(line):
    _id, info = line.split("@")
    data = {}
    for g_info in info.split(";"):
        k, v = g_info.split(":")
        data[k] = v
    return data

def optionAA(line):
    data = {}
    for g_info in line[2:].split(";"):
        k, v = g_info.split(":")
        data[k] = v
    return data

def optionB(line):
    _id, info = line.split("@")
    return dict(map(lambda i: i.split(":"), info.split(";")))

def optionC(line):
    return dict(regex.findall(line))

line = 'A@1:100;2:240;3:250;4:260;5:100;6:100;7:100;8:100;9:100;10:100'
```

Timings:

```
C:\>py -m timeit -s "import x" "x.optionA(x.line)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.35 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "import x" "x.optionAA(x.line)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.17 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "import x" "x.optionB(x.line)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.3 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "import x" "x.optionC(x.line)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.8 usec per loop
```

So it looks like the modified `optionAA` wins with this particular line.  Hopefully this shows the importance of measuring algorithms.  I'm surprised `findall` was slower.

Comment: Well, I liked your alternative. I just need to see how it behaves for more than two groups, I mean, in case `line = 'A@1:100;2:240;3:122;...'`

Comment: @RicardoSilveira The possibility of longer inputs must be specified in your question.

Comment: @RicardoSilveira, `dict(re.findall(r'(\d+):(\d+)',line))` would be a quick way to find all pairs, but you really should update your question with that requirement.

Comment: Sorry, I have just updated it. It is because when I wrote option A and B, I thought I had let it clear that it could be longer.

Comment: @RicardoSilveira, I made some timings with a longer line.  See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of using a compiled regexp to match your pattern.

```
import re

s = "A@1:100;2:240"
compiledre = re.compile("A@(\d+):(\d+);(\d+):(\d+)$")
res = compiledre.search(s)
if res:
    print dict([(res.group(1),res.group(2)),(res.group(3),res.group(4))])
```

Output is:

```
{'1': '100', '2': '240'}
```